# How do I use any webapp as a Chrome app in Windows 10 that doesn't close, just minimizes as a background app, when I click the top-right x?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, gmail, shortcuts

I have my Google Calendar and Gmail setup as apps (they're Chrome apps / websites shortcuts created in Chrome using Settings > More tools > Create application shortcuts...) in my Taskbar in Windows 10. But I'd like to treat them as background apps that stay open whether I click the minimize or close buttons at the top right.

Comment: Very old question... are you still using this setup (Windows 10 / websites as app)? Are you still interested on this?